# Is there any JS function to Uncomment, already commented HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="div1">bar</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function comment(element){
    element.wrap(function() {
        return '<!--' + this.outerHTML + '"-->';
    });
}

comment($('#div1'));
```

I want to uncomment HTML using JQuery, Please help

http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/THBpD/27/

Comment: @Parsa  Don't know how to play with the node and nodetype that is not working for Uncommenting the html for me

Comment: Can you please explain your purpose and goal ? If you just need to display or not, block depending on rules, you should work with attributes like display. Commenting makes sense when you need to explain your code. Display none on a div with a "comment" className then getElementByClassName in JS

Comment: So you want to uncomment, but provide code that tries to *add* comments. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your question looks strange This is my Js answer which use my proper HTML formatting.

```
<div class="comment">My div to comment<div>

<script>window.onload = function() { 
var commentDivs = getElementByClassName("comment") 
commentDivs.forEach((div) => {
div.outerHTML = "<!--" + div.outerHTML + "-->" 
}
}
</script>
```